# Individual factor significance in multilevel sPLS-DA

Tags: multilevel-analysis, discriminant-analysis, sparse, partial-least-squares

I recently was asked by reviewers to "include p-values" with my multilevel sparse partial least squares analysis. In brief, I have a nested design with two factors, say treatment and sampling region. Treatment is a binary factor, the sampling region has three levels. I am using the multilevel sPLS-DA as suggested in [this paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2105-13-325.pdf), resulting in an "ordination plot" like this:

[image]

I feel that the reviewer is suggesting some kind of hypothesis test to assess if individual factor levels of the sampling region influence the ordination, although I am clueless as to how I should do this.

Any pointers on this matter (preferably with R) would be very welcome.